# How to add descriptive text to plotchar() in pine-script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a simple plotchar() output that looks like this at the top of a tradingview chart;

`Sample 2.48%`

The code is below;

```
indicator('Sample', overlay=true,timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true, format=format.percent)
pct := 2.48
plotchar(pct, title="pct", char="", location=location.top, color=#ffffff)
```

I want to add some text description to the plotchar() output. I want it to look like this;

`Sample Percentage 2.48%`

I am using pinescript v5.

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=5
indicator('Sample', overlay=true,timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true, format=format.percent)
float pct = 2.48
plotchar(pct, title="Sample Percentage", char="", location=location.top, color=#ffffff)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I tested the code and it doesn't work.

Comment: It works on my side. I've added a screenshot to my answer. See "Sample Percentage" circled in red.

Comment: I see. What I want is not to have `Sample Percentage 2.48%` appear in the Data Window. What I want is to have it appear at the top left-hand corner of the chart. On your attached picture, it shows `Sample`.

Comment: @user3848207 that's not possible. `Sample` is the indicator name. You can use labels or a table to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 1):

[image: 2.5 not 2.48]

```
float pct = 2.48
plotchar(pct, title="Sample Percentage", char="", location=location.top, color=#ffffff)
```

why 2.5 not 2.48?